# Object reference is required for the non-static field method or property

Tags: c#

I have a problem with calling a method *encrypt*. It shows an error CS0210 "An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property". I tried to rectify this by adding 'static' keyword to *encrypt* method, but it also didn't work. How do I fix this?

```
class Program
{
    string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTYVWXYZ";
    string alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input text to encrypt: ");
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Input key: ");
        string key = Console.ReadLine();

        encrypt(text, key);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    int positionAlphabet(char letter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.Length; i++)
        {
            if (alphabet[i] == letter || alph[i] == letter)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public void encrypt(string text, string key)
    {
        string output = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            int positionLetterKey = positionAlphabet(key[i % key.Length]);
            int positionLetterText = positionAlphabet(text[i]);
            output += alphabet[(positionLetterText + positionLetterKey) % alphabet.Length];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Encryption output: \n", output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time, please say what line is in error.
Your problem is that you're trying to access a non-static method `encrypt` from a static method `Main`. If you set `encrypt` static, it still won't work because it calls `positionAlphabet` which is also non static. Fix them both and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a static keyword before the function PositionAlphabet as well. You cannot call a non-static function from another static function.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the error, but I have got another problem now. I get no output after  running the program, my encrytpion doesn't work. Do you know how to fix this? I am trying to make a Vigenere cipher.

Comment: Please elaborate on your post. Edit it with your expected output and the output that you've got right now. Then we can help you better.